# Running bash script on server from django

Tags: dotcloud

Is there a way to run a bash script at /home/dotcloud/current/app_name from within django? The file I'm trying to run is there, but I'm getting an OS error saying the file doesn't exist. I think it is something to do with the environment that django runs within on the dotcloud servers.

Comment: If the file is there with correct permissions it should work. Maybe the error is coming from inside of the script? can you post the exact error, and if possible the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @KenCochrane 's answer I had a closer look, and eventually figured out that it was Windows line ending conventions that were causing the problem (originally developed the script directly on the server and it was fine, but line conventions got switched when I copied the contents of the script and create a file which was then pushed to the server).